# Postgresql Return multiple rows, if one row satisfies a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter

I have the following table:

**Tablename: yay**

```
id | tagname |  value  
----+---------+---------
0  | Farbe   | Gelb
0  | Preis   | 1.15
0  | Thema   | Herbst
1  | Farbe   | Maigrün
1  | Preis   | 1.15
1  | Thema   | Herbst
2  | Farbe   | Schwarz
2  | Preis   | 1.15
2  | Thema   | Sommer
```

What i want is to get all rows of an id for which one or more conditions are satisfied and one or more where not.
If, for example, i want all `id` with their rows in the table where `tagname='Preis'`, `value='1.15'` and `tagname=Thema`, `value='Herbst'` is satisfied, but don't want `id` where `tagname='Farbe'`, `value='Schwarz'` becomes true. The result should look like this:

```
id | tagname |  value  
----+---------+---------
0  | Farbe   | Gelb
0  | Preis   | 1.15
0  | Thema   | Herbst
1  | Farbe   | Maigrün
1  | Preis   | 1.15
1  | Thema   | Herbst
```

When at least one condition for inclusion is met, all rows containing the `id` where the condition was met are to be in the result.
But if at least one condition for the exclusion is met, then no row of the corresponding `id` shall be in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the `id`s, you can do:

```
select id
from yay
group by id
having sum(case when tagname = 'preis' and value = '1.15' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when tagname = 'Thema' and value = 'Herbst' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when tagname = 'Farbe' and value = 'Schwarz' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each condition counts the number of matching rows.  The first two require at least one match (each) for an `id`, because of the `> 0`.  The third says there are no match, because of the `= 0`.

You can get the original data by joining back:

```
select yay.*
from yay join
     (select id
      from yay
      group by id
      having sum(case when tagname = 'preis' and value = '1.15' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when tagname = 'Thema' and value = 'Herbst' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when tagname = 'Farbe' and value = 'Schwarz' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
     ) yid
     on yay.id = yid.id;
```

Comment: That's what i've been searching for. Thank you!